# Preferred modifier order for annotated methods

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, jls, type-annotation

According to the JLS ([§8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)), the preferred order for method modifiers is

```java
Annotation public protected private abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

provided that annotations (if any) are applicable to methods (`@Target(METHOD)`). On the other hand ([§9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4)), any type annotations for the return types of non-`void` methods should immediately precede the type.

So if we have a method annotation:

```java
@Target(METHOD)
@interface MethodAnnotation {
}
```

and a type annotation:

```
@Target(TYPE_USE)
@interface TypeAnnotation {
}
```

then the right (as per the preferred coding style) modifier order for a sample method would be

```
@MethodAnnotation
public static @TypeAnnotation T foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Now consider we have a "mixed" annotation which applies to both methods and types:

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE_USE})
@interface MethodOrTypeAnnotation {
        // empty
}
```

When used on a method, such an annotation will be applied to **both** the method and its return type. What would the preferred code style be then?

```
public static @MethodOrTypeAnnotation T foo() {
        // ...
}
```

Or maybe the below version is better?

```
@MethodOrTypeAnnotation
public static T foo() {
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". My opinion is that an annotation with both `METHOD` and `TYPE_USE` would be very confusing, because it applies twice at the same time, so I say you should avoid an annotation like that. Like so many other things, just because the language allows it, doesn't mean you should use it.

Comment: @Andreas Okay, but most `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` annotations have `@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE, ElementType.TYPE_USE})`.

Comment: Really? [Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNull.html) `NonNull` is `TYPE_USE` only. Same for [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html). In [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NonNull.html) it is `METHOD` but not `TYPE_USE`. So what "most" are you referring to?

Comment: Okay, not *all* but *some*, see, for instance, `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` ([org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:15.0](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jetbrains|annotations|15.0|jar)).

Comment: Are you referring to JetBrains `@NotNull`, not `@NonNull`? If so, when given on a method it actually applies to the **return value** of the method *(null value is forbidden to **return (for methods)**)*, so I'd say you should annotate the return type, not the method. If annotating a method had meant that it applied to all parameters, like `@NonNullByDefault` does, then you should annotate the method, not the return value. Essentially, place it where it makes sense to a reader of your code, so intent is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring an annotation to be both a type annotation and declaration annotation is [bad style](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-no-annotation-on-types-and-declarations).  You should avoid creating such annotations.

The comments give as an example some `@Nullable` or `@NonNull` annotations, which are intended to work both with modern tools that process type annotations and with old tools that were written before Java had type annotations.  Such type-and-declaration annotations were a temporary measure, intended to be used until the tool supported Java 8, and should not be necessary any longer.
The [link above](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-no-annotation-on-types-and-declarations) gives other examples and how to avoid them.

That said, if you do have a Frankenstein type-and-declaration annotation, it's best to write it in the location that represents its main meaning or the one being used in this context.
In practice, the property is most often a type property and so the annotation should be written together with other type annotations, in front of a type.